# How filter combo box on client side when data is loaded using store remote filter

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have two combobox. On first combo, there's select event in controller which add's filter to get data for second combo:

```
      secondComboStore.remoteFilter = true;
    filters.push({property: 'Id', value: combo.getValue()});
```

I want second combo filter on client side based on typing characters, but problem is that on every character I type, request is send to server which I don't want.
This is second combo:

```
        xtype: 'combo',
        name: 'SomeName', 
        itemId: 'someNameId',
        fieldLabel: 'name',
        editable: true,
        allowBlank: false,
        queryParam: false,
        valueField: 'someId',
        displayField: 'someName',
        store: 'mySecondStore'
```

In that store, I have only defined model and server side service that's called on read.
So far, I've tried setting queryParam to false and setting queryMode to local, but requests are still send to server.
I've also tried on load event of mySecondStore set remoteFilter to false, but then there is no data displayed inside combo.

Edit:
if I put on store load event these lines:

```
        this.clearFilter(true);
        this.remoteFilter=false;
```

it is working only when store is first time loaded. When it's loaded again, values in combo are not filtered when I start typing.

Comment: when you want to send the request?

Comment: Only once, when value in first combo is selected, then I add remoteFilter with selected value in controller and then request is send to get data for second combo.
After that, I don't want any request is send on server when I type some text inside second combo, only that values are filtered on client side.

Comment: then you use store load in onchange event of combo box 1

Comment: I know that will solve problem, but It will cause some code refactoring I don't wanna do. Can't I somehow get same behavior on combo when using filtering and not loading?

Answer (score 1):

Set `editable` to `false`. Why you need editing in the second combo when you have a limited set of choices?

EDIT:
Use a separate store to load filtered data. Then copy it to a `mySecondStore` which is set to *local* mode. Set `editable` to `true`.

Comment: I want client side filtering. If second combo have 50 records, it would be easier for user to choose desired value if he can filter those 50 records by typing something in combo

Comment: Downvoting was not necessary. You wrote the message, and I understand what you want.

Comment: You should preload load second combo on every select of first combo. But your `mySecondStore` must be *local*. Then you will be able to filter second combo's content.

Answer (score 0):

use these two property for your second combo.

```
typeAhead: true,
forceSelection: true, // don't allow custom value typing in dropdown
queryMode: 'local'
```